# Go goroutines without mutex

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, mutex, goroutine

While running my goroutines without any mutexes when writing to shared resources I am not getting any runtime errors which I was expecting. Instead I get this output. The output from the goroutine which is writing over the shared resource is not being printed. But when I run with `go run .` I can see the runtime errors. Why is this happening?

EDIT:
I noticed the I do not get runtime errors if I build the executable and then run it. But I get them if I use the `go run .`.

```
GOROOT=C:\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\vtimo\go #gosetup
C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -i -o C:\Users\vtimo\Projects\go-concurrency\src\go_build_main_go_book_go.exe C:\Users\vtimo\Projects\go-concurrency\main.go C:\Users\vtimo\Projects\go-concurrency\book.go #gosetup
C:\Users\vtimo\Projects\go-concurrency\src\go_build_main_go_book_go.exe #gosetup
from database
from database
Title:          "The Android's Dream"
Author:         "John Scalzi"
Published:      2006

from database
Title:          "The Hobbit"
Author:         "J.R.R. Tolkien"
Published:      1937

from database
Title:          "On Basilisk Station"
Author:         "David Weber"
Published:      1993

from database
Title:          "The Hobbit"
Author:         "J.R.R. Tolkien"
Published:      1937

from database
Title:          "On Basilisk Station"
Author:         "David Weber"
Published:      1993

from database
Title:          "The Gods Themselves"
Author:         "Isaac Asimov"
Published:      1973

from database
Title:          "A Tale of Two Cities"
Author:         "Charles Dickens"
Published:      1859

Title:          "The Gods Themselves"
Author:         "Isaac Asimov"
Published:      1973

from database
Title:          "I, Robot"
Author:         "Isaac Asimov"
Published:      1950

from database
Title:          "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
Author:         "Douglas Adams"
Published:      1979


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Source code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var cache = map[int]Book{}
var rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        id := rnd.Intn(10) + 1
        wg.Add(2)
        go func(id int, group *sync.WaitGroup) {
            if b, ok := queryCache(id); ok {
                fmt.Println("from cache")
                fmt.Println(b)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id, wg)
        go func(id int, group *sync.WaitGroup) {
            if b, ok := queryDatabase(id); ok {
                fmt.Println("from database")
                fmt.Println(b)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id, wg)


    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func queryCache(id int) (Book, bool) {
    b, ok := cache[id]
    return b, ok
}

func queryDatabase(id int) (Book, bool) {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    for _, b := range books {
        if b.ID == id {
            cache[id] = b
            return b, true
        }
    }
    return Book{}, false
}
```

Comment: Race conditions don't generally lead to runtime errors, they lead to *undefined behavior*. Fix your race conditions.

Comment: The application has a data race on `cache`.   The race detector built in to maps is best-effort.  Do not assume that a program is free of data races because the program does not panic.

Comment: I know there are race conditions but when I use run it with `go run .` it throws a panic but not when I build it and run the executable.

Comment: The program in the question does not compile. Even if the program does compile, the builtin map race detector is best-effort.  It might detect a race on one run of a program and not another.  Use the [`-race` flag](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) for more comprehensive detection of data races.

Comment: "I know there are race" Okay, fine. Then the first thing to do is: Fix it! Anything else is of _no_ concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-race` flag to check if there any race condition:

example: `go run -race programfile.go`